# ‍♂️ Como usar la API de geolocalización del navegador en React?

Tags: reactjs

tengo un inconveniente al usar la API del navegador, el proyecto consta de un componente llamado WheatherApp que llama un modulo getApiGeolocalizacion.js del helper en el cual esta la lógica de obtener las coordenadas de latitud y longitud. El inconveniente que tengo es que no he podido retornar adecuadamente las coordenadas ya que al momento de llamar la api de geolocalización este tine un comportamiento ***asíncrono*** y me devuelve ***undefine*** en el componente WheatherApp. Ya he intentado con *then* o *async/await* pero no he sabido como. alguien podría guiarme si es tan amable.

```
//WheatherApp.js :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getApiGeolocalizacion } from './helpers/getApiGeolocalizacion';

export const WeatherApp = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
    
    useEffect( () => {
        
        getApiGeolocalizacion().then( data => setData(data) )

    }, [])
 
    return(
        <h1>{ data.lon }</h1>
    )
}
```

```
//getApiGeolocalizacion.js :
export const getApiGeolocalizacion = async ( ) => {
    if( !navigator.geolocation ) return
        
    const sucess = (position) => {
        let lat = position.coords.latitude;
        let lon = position.coords.longitude;
        
        return {lat, lon};
    }        

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( sucess, (err) => console.log(err) )
}
```

Comment: Revisando tu código, veo que has declarado como asíncrona la función getApiGeolocalizacion, pero luego dentro no veo un await que "detenga" la ejecución hasta obtener el resultado de la función asíncrona.

Comment: Hola @SergioGarridoDomínguez, lo siento si se me paso ese async (no debería de estar hay ), el código esta tal cual como lo proponen en los tutoriales. Cómo decía, ya intente con las promesa y el async/await pero no logre nada. lo que había intentado hacer es convertir en una promesa la función `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. para luego usar el await pero no tuve los resultado esperados.